# PHP how to check whether postfix is on

Tags: php, postfix-mta

Is it possible to check in PHP, whether postfix service is running or not? I am looking for platform independent solution (so I don't want to execute console commands within PHP code).

When I am testing my apps on localhost I often forget to start postfix and then I am curious, why I am not receiving emails :)). I would like to test somehow if service is enabled and throw an exception if not.

Comment: Postfix is *nix oriented , why you need a cross platform solution then  ?

Comment: I don't think its possible. The only thing you can do I think is something like try(mail()) but that will just check if the mail is **sent** and not if the mail has **reached his target**.

Comment: @Akhil Thayyil: But then on windows there should be some other "backend" for the "mail" function. So my question is then is there any general way how to check whether this backand is running?

Comment: Just use execute commands.

Comment: @Michal Hint: you can check what operating system your running on and perform different exec() commands. :)

Comment: @Michal i wil write this as an answer so we can close this1^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its possible. The only thing you can do I think is something like try(mail()) but that will just check if the mail is **sent** and not if the mail has **reached his target.**

Anyways, you can simply use execute commands

`exec()`

When you want to have it cross-platform you can just access the PHP constant

`PHP_OS`

which gives you the information about what operating system your running on. Then just execute different `exec()` commands for each operating system and your done =).